# Select from 2 tables in Symfony2

Tags: database, symfony, query-builder

I am making a query inside a form.

The idea is : Now I have a dropdown with all the users, ok?

I have a query like this:

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
      return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.lastName', 'ASC');
     }
```

This works flawless!

Instead of displaying all the users, I only need the users that are associated with a category. This definition is in the "user_data" table (user_id + category_id).

So, I need to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_data WHERE category_id='2')
```

I don't have any entity that looks like UserData, I only have User.php, but inside this file I found this:

```
/**
     *@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="My\Bundle\Entity\Data", inversedBy="users")
     *@ORM\joinTable(name="user_data")
     */
    protected $datas;

[...]
```

So I see that a relationship is build, but I don't get it how to use it in order to build my query based on the 2 tables...

Anyone can help me with this issue? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
              ->innerJoin('u.datas', 'd')
              ->where('d.category = :category') // Check your Data entity to get the right field name
              ->setParameter('category', $yourCategoryId) // you could use options here
              ->orderBy('u.lastName', 'ASC');
     }
```

Also, update your question with all your entities (Data, ...)

Comment: I think it's working... i just want to test it in more details. (then I'll accept the answer)

Thanks a lot @ahmed-siouani - just one last question - can you point me to the place where this process is described in order to better understand it? Thanks!

Comment: @Ka7anax You're welcome.

But what do you mean by "this process is described"?, Do you mean "[documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html)"?  Also check [Sf2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#using-doctrine-s-query-builder).

Comment: Yes! I'll look there... the idea is that I want to understand the way it works all this database query-methods in Symfony!

I'll search a good tutorial explaining all this Entity-Database-Form relationship (how to query the database in order to display different information in forms. If you have one, don't hesitate to share it :)